# php search on comma separated string and get matching element

Tags: php, regex, string, filter, preg-match

I have a question, if anyone can help me to solve this. 
I have a string, and I want to find an item that matches from search :

```
$search = "vox,eleciones,Gobierno";
$string = "El Gobierno de Pedro Sánchez ahonda en el trato de favor a País Vasco y Navarra";

$regex = '/([^,]*' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '[^,]*)/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $match);

$result = trim($match[1]);
print_r($result);
```

Result must be :"El Gobierno de Pedro Sánchez ahonda en el trato de favor a País Vasco y Navarra"

Comment: What output are you getting from the code? Is there an error?

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is `$regex = '/\b(' . implode('|', explode(',', $search)) . ')\b/';`

Comment: What do you mean by "matches"? The given string to search in does not contain `vox,eleciones,Gobierno`

Comment: thanx @Nick, yes it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$search = "vox,eleciones,Gobierno";
$string = "El Gobierno de Pedro Sánchez ahonda en el trato de favor a País Vasco y Navarra";

$search = explode(",", $search);
$expression = '/\b(?:' . implode("|", $search) . ')\b/i';

```
            if(preg_match($expression, $string,$match)){
```

//success
}